Problem with customized Linear Regression
I am learning ML and going through learning models. My latest task was to write a multiple linear regression model with MSE optimization(without using the existing one in sklearn) and test it with data.
My model is:
  def linear_regression(x: np.array, y: np.array, learning_speed: float = 0.1, echoes: int = 1000):

      n = len(y)
      coef = np.zeros(len(x[0]) + 1)

      for _ in range(echoes):

            d = np.array([]) # Array to contain a step for each coef

            for idx in range(len(coef)):
                d_coef = 0
                for row in range(len(x)):
                    if idx == len(coef) - 1:
                        d_coef += (1) * (np.sum(coef[:-1] * x[row]) + coef[-1] - y[row])
                    else:
                        d_coef += (x[row, idx]) * (np.sum(coef[:-1] * x[row]) - y[row] + coef[-1]) # Sum of derivatives of (V1X1 + ... + VnXn + b - y) related to coef idx
                  d = np.append(d, (2 / n) * d_coef)
                  
              coef -= learning_speed * d

    print(f'coef = {coef[:-1]}')
    print(f'b = {coef[-1]}')

After I have tested the model with some datasets. For small datasets it worked perfectly. But then I have tried the bigger one:
x1_rnd = np.array([])
x2_rnd = np.array([])
c1 = 5
c2 = 0.75
b = 15
for _ in range(500):
    x1_rnd = np.append(x1_rnd, np.random.randint(1, 100))
    x2_rnd = np.append(x2_rnd, np.random.randint(1, 100))

combo = zip(x1_rnd, x2_rnd)
x = np.array([list(elem) for elem in combo])
y_rnd = c1 * x1_rnd + c2 * x2_rnd + b

And my model has a significant error. Even with 20000 iterations (and learn speed = 0.0001) it predicts more or less the coefficients for X1 and X2 but stays very far from prediction of "b". I have noticed that smaller "b" results in better prediction while greater is worsening it (like if it is 0.1 the model works right and fast; if b = 100, it is a nigthmare).
I can´t find any error in my code gradient descent. Please, help to resolve it!
